# What happens if someone teleports from the Nether past the 3,750,000 X/Z coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether):

> Locations in the Nether correlate to Overworld coordinates, but horizontal Overworld distances are scaled down by a ratio of 8:1 for travel in the Nether. Therefore, travelling one block in the Nether means travelling 8 blocks in the Overworld.

So, the 3,750,000 horizontal coordinate correlates to the 30,000,000 (The world's limit), what happens if someone teleports past the 3,750,000 X/Z coordinate in the Nether. **Will he/she be teleported outside of the world?**

Answer (score 3):

*The game limits the teleport location to ±2,999,886 horizontal axis, no matter the Nether portal's location.*
I've tested it, first teleporting from a portal located a few blocks past the 3,750,000 coordinate, and then from a portal located several hundreds blocks away from the first, and **the Overworld's corresponding location was the same.**

Comment: This is likely because of the world border. [See the trivia section on the wiki about it](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border#Trivia).  The world border ends at  ±2,999,886 specifically to prevent players from falling through the world.

Comment: The world border starts at  ±2,999,984, what have you meant? @TimmyJim

Comment: I didn't realize your number was +2 than the wikis.  Are you saying you teleported out of bounds then?

Comment: I wrote 2,999,**8**84, not 2,999,**9**84. That's a little farther than the border. @TimmyJim

Comment: Ahh I see! I guess its a hard coded "safe zone".  Sorry, I've been starring at numbers all day.  Disregard my comments.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's a safe zone. @TimmyJim